# Configure Visual Studio and Meteor

Tags: meteor, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use mac visual studio to debug my meteor application. I can't quite figure out how to get it to do anything in `attach` mode.  Here is what I am doing:

1) run `meteor debug --settings settings-development.json`

2) Use the following attach configuration in the launch.json file:

```
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858,
        "address": "localhost",
        "restart": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": null
    }
```

3) Press the debug attach command. The bottom of the visual studio code turns brown indicating that is connected.

4) Add a breakpoint in my index.jsx file on the first line:

```
        {getThirdReasons().map((reason) => (
          <Reason key={ reason._id } reason={ reason } />
        ))}
```

At this point nothing happens at all. I can get this to work in webstorm, what should I be doing here? I know that I should have a indicator in chrome but I don't, and I don't think I need to install a chrome plugin like I did with webstorm.

Additionally if someone has figured out how to launch meteor from visual studio instead of attaching that would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: do you use the VS IDE or the VS code? Which Version? Do you use the Meteor Tools for Visual Studio https://meteortools.codeplex.com/?

Comment: I use vs code and I don't use meteor tools because they don't provide a download so I think it is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The `outDir` attribute is deprecated in the VSCode 1.6.1 that I am trying to use.
The tooltip that pops up when positioning the mouse on `outDir` says: *use outFiles attribute instead.*

So you can try to remove the outDir pair and replace it with:

```
"outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js"],
```